# How can we call a spring controller (*.do action) using an AJAX call from a JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

How can we call a spring controller (*.do action) using an AJAX call from a JS file?

I want to call spring controller from AJAX controller, while making an AJAX call i want to forward my request to an spring controller.

Comment: better to search in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't catch the problem. Here is an example :

```
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url: "yourUrlToTheController.do",
                success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

                },
                error : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){

                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did the same.